# How to apply a color format condition to a range of cells and highlight the line that matches the condition?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, range

I have code (I got in a forum) for a CommandButton macro, that selects a wide range of cells in a worksheet, and highlights the selected cells background in different colors, depending on each of the three button states.

I adjusted the code a bit:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Nam As Variant
Static c
Nam = Array("A", "B", "C", vbYellow, vbCyan, vbWhite)
If c = 3 Or c = "" Then c = 0
CommandButton1.Caption = Nam(c)
CommandButton1.BackColor = Nam(c + 3)

Range("A:G").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Select Case Nam(c)
    Case "A": Range("A1:U1000").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Case "B": Range("A1:U1000").Interior.ColorIndex = 8
    Case "C": Range("A1:U1000").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End Select
c = c + 1
End Sub
```

But I need that for each button state, it highlights (in each color of the three button states) only the rows of the selection block that contain a value inside an specific cell, which is always in the same column, inside each row.

Something like this:

If button state is A, then all the rows that contain an "y" inside the cell **Jn** (J1, J2, J3...) get highlighted in the color set by A. Something like If (Jn = "y") then highlight the whole line... n = n+ 1.... Goes to next line... repeat...

If button state is B, then all the rows that contain an "n" inside the cell Jn get highlighted in the color set by B

If button state is C, then all the rows that contain "y" or "n" get back to no fill in their cells...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Select statement, assign the ColorIndex to a variable. Then loop through each row in your range and check if each column J meets your criteria. If it does, apply the ColorIndex to that row.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Nam As Variant
Static c
Nam = Array("A", "B", "C", vbYellow, vbCyan, vbWhite)
If c = 3 Or c = "" Then c = 0
CommandButton1.Caption = Nam(c)
CommandButton1.BackColor = Nam(c + 3)

Range("A:G").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

Dim NewColor As Long
Select Case Nam(c)
    Case "A": NewColor = 6
    Case "B": NewColor = 8
    Case "C": NewColor = 0
End Select

Dim rg As Range
Dim i As Long
Set rg = Range("A1:U1000")
For i = 1 To rg.Rows.Count
    If Cells(i, "J") = "y" Then Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i, "U")).Interior.ColorIndex = NewColor
Next i
c = c + 1
End Sub
```